# How Inshorts implement the sharing card feature

Tags: android, android-layout

In the Inshorts app, when you click on the share button. It shares the `news card` with a modified image of the card. How it does that.

I can think of doing it by changing the `view` to a bitmap and then storing on file system temporarily, and then trigger an `intent` of sharing the image among various apps like WhatsApp / facebook etc.

Is there any other method available to do that, instead of bitmap conversation.

Comment: do u get a solution?

Comment: I did it by converting the whole view to Bitmap, saving it to an image in expternal storage and then firing an intent.

Comment: can we create bitmap of a view, that is not shown ? i mean i want to share a view which is different than what is shown.

Comment: can u share your code?